# Issue with uploading multiple files Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've been trying to upload multiple files to Firebase Storage in my Angular application. However, I've encountered an issue. When I upload a single file, everything works fine. It uploads the image to storage and associates it with a product. I have two tables, product and product_image to store images associated with products. The products will depend on categories types

However, the problem arises when I select two or more images to upload. In this case, it still uploads the images to Firebase Storage, but the product is stored as an ID instead of the actual product, as it should be.

```
export class ProductImageDialogComponent implements OnInit{

  form!:FormGroup;
  categories:Category[] = [];
  products:Product[] = [];
  selectedCategory:Category;
  selectedImages:File[] =[];

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
              private categoryService:CategoryService,
              private productService:ProductService,
              private productImageService:ProductImageService,
              private utilService:UtilService,
              private matDialog:MatDialogRef<ProductImageDialogComponent>,
              private storage: Storage) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategories();
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group<ProductImage>({
      product: null,
      status: true,
    })
  }

  onCategoryChange(selectedCategory:Category){
    this.productService.getProductsByCategory(selectedCategory.id).subscribe(
      {
        next:(data)=>{
          this.products = data
        },
        error: err=>{
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    )
  }

  onFileChange(event:any){
    if(event.target.files.length > 0 && event.target.files){
      for(let i=0; i<event.target.files.length;i++){
        this.selectedImages.push(event.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  getCategories(){
    return this.categoryService.getCategoryList()
      .subscribe({
        next:(data)=>{
          this.categories = data;
        },
        error:(err)=>{
          this.utilService.openSnackBar(err, 'Đóng');
        }
      })
  }
  onSubmit(){
    if(this.form.valid){
          for(let i =0 ;i <this.selectedImages.length; i++){
            this.createProductImageWithImage(this.selectedImages[i]);
          }
      }
    }
  }
  getCurrentDateTime(){
    return formatDate(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyyTHH:MM:SSa', 'en-us');
  }    

  createProductImageWithImage(image:File){
    const imgName = this.getCurrentDateTime() + image.name;
    const storageRef = ref(this.storage, `coffee/${this.form.get('product')?.get('name')?.getRawValue()}/${imgName}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot)=>{
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      },
      (err)=>{
        this.utilService.openSnackBar(err.message, 'Close');
        console.log(err);
      },
      ()=>{
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL)=>{
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
          // this.form.value.image = downloadURL;
          this.createProductImage({name: imgName, url: downloadURL, product: this.form.get('product').value});
        })
      })
  }

  createProductImage(image:ProductImage){
    this.productImageService.createProductImage(image).subscribe({
      next:() => {
        this.utilService.openSnackBar('Success', 'Close')
        this.matDialog.close(true);
        console.log(this.form)
      },
      error:(err) => {
        this.utilService.openSnackBar(err.message, 'Close');
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

*ProductImageDialogComponent HTML*

```
<div class="" mat-dialog-title>
  <h1>Images</h1>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="content" mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Categories</mat-label>
          <mat-select [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (ngModelChange)="onCategoryChange($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let c of categories" [value]="c">{{c.name}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Products</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="product">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let p of products" [value]="p">{{p.name}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Upload</mat-label>
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="action" mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" [mat-dialog-close]="false">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

*Model*

```
export interface ProductImage{
  id?:number
  name?:string,
  url?:string,
  createdAt?:Date,
  updatedAt?:Date,
  status?:boolean,
  product?:Product,
}

export interface Product{
  id?:number;
  name:string;
  quantity:number;
  sold:number;
  description:string;
  price:number;
  createdAt:Date;
  status:boolean;
  category:Category;
  flavor:Flavor;
  sale:Sale;
}
```

Result when I upload 1 and more than 2 images in JSON

```
// When upload 1 image
        {
                "id": 109,
                "name": "13-09-2023T22:09:37PM279349412_523467566113188_4869464094943884936_n.jpg",
                "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/filtro-1aa65.appspot.com/o/coffee%2Fundefined%2F13-09-2023T22%3A09%3A37PM279349412_523467566113188_4869464094943884936_n.jpg?alt=media&token=9311b5bf-3fc4-4332-8736-d0a78af9ae60",
                "createdAt": "2023-09-12T17:00:00.000+00:00",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "test12",
                    "quantity": 15,
                    "sold": 0,
                    "price": 15,
                    "description": "asdsadaxd",
                    "createdAt": "2023-09-12T16:43:18",
                    "status": false,
                    "flavor": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "test11",
                        "description": "test234",
                        "status": true
                    },
                    "category": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "test2",
                        "status": false
                    },
                    "sale": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "test",
                        "description": "asdasd",
                        "start": null,
                        "end": null,
                        "discount": 15,
                        "status": true
                    }
                }
            }
    
    // when upload more than 2 images
            {
                "id": 110,
                "name": "13-09-2023T22:09:93PMLavazza_Club.jpg",
                "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/filtro-1aa65.appspot.com/o/coffee%2Fundefined%2F13-09-2023T22%3A09%3A93PMLavazza_Club.jpg?alt=media&token=5f589338-b692-4344-8aaa-9cc790415c7c",
                "createdAt": "2023-09-12T17:00:00.000+00:00",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "product": 7 <-- should be a product
            },
            {
                "id": 111,
                "name": "13-09-2023T22:09:93PMTEMT (16).jpg",
                "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/filtro-1aa65.appspot.com/o/coffee%2Fundefined%2F13-09-2023T22%3A09%3A93PML%E1%BA%A1c%20gi%E1%BB%AFa%20kh%C3%B4ng%20trung_%20(16).jpg?alt=media&token=a2ac05cf-26e2-420d-a434-e2da77672afb",
                "createdAt": "2023-09-12T17:00:00.000+00:00",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "product": 7 <-- should be a product
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error is in the backend (I'm using Spring Boot) due to improper use of @JsonIdentityInfo, which caused the issue. Reference these topics help me alot

[Unable to get JsonIdentityInfo to work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578480/unable-to-get-jsonidentityinfo-to-work-correctly)

[Ignore the Jackson JsonIdentityInfo during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991236/ignore-the-jackson-jsonidentityinfo-during-serialization)